# Moved swiftUI view into UIKit project but assets no longer appear in Preview

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, assets

I have an existing app built with UIKit and wanted to integrate a SwiftUI view into it. To begin, I built a separate SwiftUI app in my workspace and after I had the basics working I added the code into my original project.

The original views from UIKit use the images just fine and they also appeared just fine with the code in its original SwiftUI app, but **when I'm running the preview on my views in the original app it's been transported into the string references don't seem to work and the images don't show.**

The code clearly isn't the issue, since it works fine in the other app, and the references should be fine since I just straight copied the assets folder over; but here's an example just in case...

```
@ViewBuilder
func customIcon(image named: String, multiplier: Double = 1.0) -> some View {
    Image(named)
        .interpolation(.none)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 15 * multiplier,
               height: 12 * multiplier,
               alignment: .leading)
}
```

I'm very new to SwiftUI, so I'm wondering if there's some setting or configuration issue involved? All of the code and assets are in the same package and when I use that package's associated scheme the preview builds and the button logic works fine.

**UPDATE**

So I wired up the new view to a button call in my app using `UIHostingController` and the images appear in simulator just not in the preview.

Obviously I can move forward like this, but I'd prefer to have access to the previewer while working on my views going forward. I've cleaned product, deleted derived data and rebooted computer.

**Is there some configuration for the previewer to access the bundle resources?**

Comment: It is not about SwiftUI, it is rather in project configuration, either assets not in target or not copied or something else.

Comment: The assets are working in the same project using UIKit and working. The references are the same.